# Chain Rule for derivatives: $\frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(x, y) dy \right) $

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification, chain-rule

Let $$f(x) =  \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(x, y) dy $$

I want to find $f'(x_0) $ using chain rule.

**Solution**

Let \begin{align*}\mathbb{R} \stackrel{h_1}{\to} \mathbb{R}^3 \stackrel{h_2}{\to} \mathbb{R}\end{align*}

where $h_1(x) = (x, x, x)$ and $$h_2(x_1, x_2, x_3) =  \int_{a(x_2)}^{b(x_1)} g(x_3, y) dy$$

Then, $f = h_2 \circ h_1$ 
\begin{align*}
f'(x_0) &= h_2'(h_1(x_0)) . h_1'(x_0)\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial h_2 }{\partial x_1}\Big|_{(x_0, x_0, x_0)} & \frac{\partial h_2 }{\partial x_2}\Big|_{(x_0, x_0, x_0)} & \frac{\partial h_2 }{\partial x_3}\Big|_{(x_0, x_0, x_0)} 
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    1\\
    1
    \end{bmatrix}\\
\\
&= \frac{\partial h_2 }{\partial x_1}\Big|_{(x_0, x_0, x_0)} + \frac{\partial h_2 }{\partial x_2}\Big|_{(x_0, x_0, x_0)} + \frac{\partial h_2 }{\partial x_3}\Big|_{(x_0, x_0, x_0)} \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Lastly, I have:

$$\frac{\partial h_2 }{\partial x_1}\Big|_{(x_0, x_0, x_0)} = g(x_0, b(x_0)).b'(x_0) \tag{2}$$

$$\frac{\partial h_2 }{\partial x_2}\Big|_{(x_0, x_0, x_0)} = -g(x_0, a(x_0)).a'(x_0) \tag{3} $$

$$\frac{\partial h_2 }{\partial x_3}\Big|_{(x_0, x_0, x_0)} = g(x_0, b(x_0)) - g(x_0, a(x_0)) \tag{4}$$

Plugging this back in $(1)$ I believe is the final solution.

I want to verify this solution especially $(2)$, $(3)$ and $(4)$ and get corrections (if any).

Comment: Equation (4) is not correct because the integral does not undo the derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x_3}$ should be
$$\int_{a(x_2)}^{b(x_1)}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_3}(x_3,y)dy$$. Thus the final answer is
 $$f'(x_0)=g(x_0,b(x_0))b'(x_0)-g(x_0,a(x_0))a'(x_0)$$ 
$$+\int_{a(x_0)}^{b(x_0)}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_0,y)dy$$